# Removing lines from file python

Tags: python

I have a file that looks something like

```
geneA geneB 134
geneC geneF 395
geneH geneD 958
geneF geneC 395
geneB geneA 134
geneD geneH 958
```

I would like to remove the lines that have the same genes (that are in opposite order) so I just get

```
geneA geneB 134
geneC geneF 395
geneH geneD 958
```

I have this so far, but I get even more duplicates when I try using replace() or an if not statement. Any ideas on how I could change this?

```
with open(filename, 'r') as handle, open(outfilename, 'a') as w:

    for line in handle:
        element = line.split()
        gene1 = element[0]
        gene2 = element[1]

        for line in handle:
            matchingelement = line.split()
            gene3 = matchingelement[0]
            gene4 = matchingelement[1]

            if gene3 == gene2 and gene4 == gene1:
                """Remove the line"""
```

Comment: By "remove this line" do you mean remove it and write the same file again or remove it and write the results in a new file?

Comment: Will lines with the same genes always have the same number in the end?

Comment: I'd like to write whatever is left to a new file. They will always have the same number, but I was trying to avoid using that just in case a connection between two genes happens to have the same value as a connection between two other genes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert the genes into a hashable form that can be added to a set and check that set as you go along. In this example, I sorted the genes so that order doesn't matter and then build them back into a single "normalized" string.

```
filename = 'a.txt'
outfilename = 'aout.txt'

seen = set()

with open(filename, 'r') as handle, open(outfilename, 'a') as w:
    for line in handle:
        element = line.split()
        # a hashable "normalized" view of the genes
        genes = '-'.join(sorted(element[0:2]))
        if genes not in seen:
            seen.add(genes)
            w.write(line)

print(open(outfilename).read())
```

Comment: I can't seem to figure this out for some reason... `element` will only have 3 elements `['geneX', 'geneY', '123']`, right? Why `element[0:3]`?

Comment: @VladislavMartin - you are right that should have been [0:2]. thanks!

Comment: Even then isn't that the same as `element`? Because `element` only has 3 items so the `[0:2]` won't make a difference. I'm probably missing something simple haha

Comment: @Farhan.K - slices are open-ended on the right so `0:2` selects elements 0 and 1. As an example, `['geneA', 'geneB', '134'][0:2]` gives you `['geneA', 'geneB']`.

Comment: @tdelaney I can't believe I forgot that. Knew it was something simple, thanks